# How to optimize search through emails to find text using MS Access VBA 2016?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have working code taking about 30 seconds to search 80 emails.

We have about 12 users working out of this database and are getting errors when two or more people are updating their email lists. I tried basing this out of a table instead but that took nearly four times longer.

```vb
'search the body
If InStr(.Body, "hsarep") Or InStr(.Body, "repcosalesofga") Or InStr(.Body, "p-massoc") Or InStr(.Body, "tchristy") Or InStr(.Body, "mlsalesinc") Or _
InStr(.Body, "vcmsales") Or InStr(.Body, "ssafla") Or InStr(.Body, "bellsouth") Or InStr(.Body, "jim-bryce") Or InStr(.Body, "millermays") Or _
InStr(.Body, "kennymma") Or InStr(.Body, "hhrep") Or InStr(.Body, "bankcs@aol") Or InStr(.Body, "dtoddcpd") Or InStr(.Body, "colleenmartinhandh") Or _
InStr(.Body, "ppg-sales") Or InStr(.Body, "asapsales") Or InStr(.Body, "mechagents") Or InStr(.Body, "e-technical@zurn.com") Or _
InStr(.Body, "Barbara.Cass") Or InStr(.Body, "Craig.Comito") Or _
InStr(.Body, "comfortsystemsusa") Or InStr(.Body, "hmmechanical") Or InStr(.Body, "gsphinc") Or InStr(.Body, "dynaten") Or InStr(.Body, "ColonialWebb") Or _
InStr(.Body, "bchmechanical") Or InStr(.Body, "rbiva") Or InStr(.Body, "naminc") Or InStr(.Body, "designmech") Or InStr(.Body, "marelich") Or _
InStr(.Body, "gowaninc") Or InStr(.Body, "emcorgroup") Or InStr(.Body, "emcor") Or InStr(.Body, "comunale") Or InStr(.Body, "shambaugh") Or _
InStr(.Body, "trautman-shreve") Or InStr(.Body, "ccimechanical") Or InStr(.Body, "scaliseindustries") Or InStr(.Body, "cannistraro") Or InStr(.Body, "brand") Or _
InStr(.Body, "mckenneys") Or InStr(.Body, "murphy-stl") Or InStr(.Body, "eganco") Or InStr(.Body, "jfahern") Or InStr(.Body, "hillgrp") Or _
InStr(.Body, "jhkelly") Or InStr(.Body, "ewing-doherty") Or InStr(.Body, "falconplumbing") Or InStr(.Body, "hmcc") Or InStr(.Body, "harriscompany") Or _
InStr(.Body, "hpeinc") Or InStr(.Body, "jjkllc") Or InStr(.Body, "jwdanforth") Or InStr(.Body, "murraycompany") Or InStr(.Body, "southlandind") Or _
InStr(.Body, "usengineering") Or InStr(.Body, "kruckph") Or InStr(.Body, "ppcosa") Or InStr(.Body, "ppmechanical") Or InStr(.Body, "northmechanical") Or _
InStr(.Body, "welchandrushe") Or InStr(.Body, "acibuilds") Or InStr(.Body, "waldinger") Or InStr(.Body, "precisionplumbing") Or InStr(.Body, "osullivanplmg") Or _
InStr(.Body, "mmccontractors") Then

    ProjectID = "PLA-" & Format(Initial_Contact, "yyyy_mm_dd-hhnnss")
    
'search sender address
ElseIf InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "hsarep") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "repcosalesofga") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "p-massoc") Or _
InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "tchristy") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "mlsalesinc") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "vcmsales") Or _
InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "ssafla") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "bellsouth") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "jim-bryce") Or _
InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "millermays") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "kennymma") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "hhrep") Or _
InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "bankcs@aol") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "dtoddcpd") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "colleenmartinhandh") Or _
InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "ppg-sales") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "asapsales") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "mechagents") Or _
InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Jon.Huddle") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Jonathan.Huddle") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Dennis.Haeberlin") Or _
InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Jon.Drobac") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "John.McNutt") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Mark.Marini") Or _
InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Frank.Schaetzke") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Dave.Gomo") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Bill.Woehlke") Or _
InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Joe.Clarey") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Joe.Cunningham") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Donald.Cormany") Or _
InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Jim.Fessler") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Eddy.Edmunds") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Alan.Squires") Or _
InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Brian.Gillespie") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "e-technical@zurn.com") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Lyndsey.Smith") Or _
InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Jim.Stafford") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Eric.Klump") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Ryan.Langan") Or _
InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Barbara.Cass") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Craig.Comito") Then

    ProjectID = "PLA-" & Format(Initial_Contact, "yyyy_mm_dd-hhnnss")

' Regular Email
ProjectID = "E-" & Format(Initial_Contact, "yyyy_mm_dd_hhnnss")
End If
```

I would like the time it takes to run this code to be closer to 10 seconds or less.

The rest of the code.

```vb
Public Function AppEmailSearch()
On Error GoTo errhndlr
'----------------------------------Timer-----------------------------------
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
StartTime = Timer
'----------------------------------Timer-----------------------------------
    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim AppInbox As Outlook.folder
    Dim Email As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim Count As Integer
    Dim EntryID, From, Subject, ProjectID As String
    Dim Initial_Contact, ETA As Date
        
    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set AppInbox = ns.GetFolderFromID(DLookup("Location", "List_FileLocations", "[LocationName] = 'AppEngr_Inbox'"))
    
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Email_Info", dbOpenDynaset)
    Count = AppInbox.Items.Count
            
    For Each Email In AppInbox.Items
        With Email
            EntryID = .EntryID
            Subject = .Subject
            Initial_Contact = .ReceivedTime
            
      '      ETA = Functions.ETA(CStr(Initial_Contact), "E", 0)
            
            Select Case .SenderName
            
            ' System Specifier Emails
            Case "specifier@flothru.com"
                ProjectID = "SSE-" & Format(Initial_Contact, "yyyy_mm_dd-hhnnss")
                Dim Beginning As Integer
             Beginning = InStr(.Body, "http://") - 1
                From = Right(.Body, Len(.Body) - Beginning)
                
            ' Platinum Emails
            Case "Zurn-Platinum"
                ProjectID = "PLA-" & Format(Initial_Contact, "yyyy_mm_dd-hhnnss")
                From = .SenderName
                
            Case Else
                'search the body
'                If InStr(.Body, "hsarep") Or InStr(.Body, "repcosalesofga") Or InStr(.Body, "p-massoc") Or InStr(.Body, "tchristy") Or InStr(.Body, "mlsalesinc") Or _
'                InStr(.Body, "vcmsales") Or InStr(.Body, "ssafla") Or InStr(.Body, "bellsouth") Or InStr(.Body, "jim-bryce") Or InStr(.Body, "millermays") Or _
'                InStr(.Body, "kennymma") Or InStr(.Body, "hhrep") Or InStr(.Body, "bankcs@aol") Or InStr(.Body, "dtoddcpd") Or InStr(.Body, "colleenmartinhandh") Or _
'                InStr(.Body, "ppg-sales") Or InStr(.Body, "asapsales") Or InStr(.Body, "mechagents") Or InStr(.Body, "e-technical@zurn.com") Or _
'                InStr(.Body, "Barbara.Cass") Or InStr(.Body, "Craig.Comito") Then
                
'                    ProjectID = "PLA-" & Format(Initial_Contact, "yyyy_mm_dd-hhnnss")
                    
                'search sender address
'                ElseIf InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "hsarep") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "repcosalesofga") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "p-massoc") Or _
'                InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "tchristy") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "mlsalesinc") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "vcmsales") Or _
'                InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "ssafla") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "bellsouth") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "jim-bryce") Or _
'                InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "millermays") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "kennymma") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "hhrep") Or _
'                InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "bankcs@aol") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "dtoddcpd") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "colleenmartinhandh") Or _
'                InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "ppg-sales") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "asapsales") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "mechagents") Or _
'                InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Jon.Huddle") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Jonathan.Huddle") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Dennis.Haeberlin") Or _
'                InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Jon.Drobac") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "John.McNutt") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Mark.Marini") Or _
'                InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Frank.Schaetzke") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Dave.Gomo") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Bill.Woehlke") Or _
'                InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Joe.Clarey") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Joe.Cunningham") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Donald.Cormany") Or _
'                InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Jim.Fessler") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Eddy.Edmunds") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Alan.Squires") Or _
'                InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Brian.Gillespie") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "e-technical@zurn.com") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Lyndsey.Smith") Or _
'                InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Jim.Stafford") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Eric.Klump") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Ryan.Langan") Or _
'                InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Barbara.Cass") Or InStr(.SenderEmailAddress, "Craig.Comito") Then
                
'                    ProjectID = "PLA-" & Format(Initial_Contact, "yyyy_mm_dd-hhnnss")
                
                ' Regular Email
'                Else
'                ProjectID = "E-" & Format(Initial_Contact, "yyyy_mm_dd_hhnnss")
'                End If

                If SearchString(.Body, "hsarep,repcosalesofga,p-massoc,tchristy,mlsalesinc,vcmsales,ssafla,bellsouth,jim-bryce,millermays,kennymma,hhrep,bankcs@aol,dtoddcpd,colleenmartinhandh,ppg-sales,asapsales,mechagents,e-technical@zurn.com,Barbara.Cass,Craig.Comito,comfortsystemsusa,hmmechanical,gsphinc,dynaten,ColonialWebb,_bchmechanical,rbiva,naminc,designmech,marelich,gowaninc,emcorgroup,emcor,comunale,shambaugh,trautman-shreve,ccimechanical,scaliseindustries,cannistraro,brand,mckenneys,murphy-stl,eganco,jfahern,hillgrp,jhkelly,ewing-doherty,falconplumbing,hmcc,harriscompany,hpeinc,jjkllc,jwdanforth,murraycompany,southlandind,usengineering,kruckph,ppcosa,ppmechanical,northmechanical,welchandrushe,acibuilds,waldinger,precisionplumbing,osullivanplmg,mmccontractors") Then
                    ProjectID = "PLA-" & Format(Initial_Contact, "yyyy_mm_dd-hhnnss")
                ElseIf SearchString(.SenderEmailAddress, "hsarep,repcosalesofga,p-massoc,tchristy,mlsalesinc,vcmsales,ssafla,bellsouth,jim-bryce,millermays,kennymma,hhrep,bankcs@aol,dtoddcpd,colleenmartinhandh,ppg-sales,asapsales,mechagents,Jon.Huddle,Jonathan.Huddle,Dennis.Haeberlin,Jon.Drobac,John.McNutt,Mark.Marini,Frank.Schaetzke,Dave.Gomo,Bill.Woehlke,Joe.Clarey,Joe.Cunningham,Donald.Cormany,Jim.Fessler,Eddy.Edmunds,Alan.Squires,Brian.Gillespie,e-technical@zurn.com,Lyndsey.Smith,Jim.Stafford,Eric.Klump,Ryan.Langan,Barbara.Cass,Craig.Comito") Then
                    ProjectID = "PLA-" & Format(Initial_Contact, "yyyy_mm_dd-hhnnss")
                ElseIf SearchString(.SenderEmailAddress, "comfortsystemsusa,hmmechanical,gsphinc,dynaten,ColonialWebb,_bchmechanical,rbiva,naminc,designmech,marelich,gowaninc,emcorgroup,emcor,comunale,shambaugh,trautman-shreve,ccimechanical,scaliseindustries,cannistraro,brand,mckenneys,murphy-stl,eganco,jfahern,hillgrp,jhkelly,ewing-doherty,falconplumbing,hmcc,harriscompany,hpeinc,jjkllc,jwdanforth,murraycompany,southlandind,usengineering,kruckph,ppcosa,ppmechanical,northmechanical,welchandrushe,acibuilds,waldinger,precisionplumbing,osullivanplmg,mmccontractors") Then
                    ProjectID = "PLA-" & Format(Initial_Contact, "yyyy_mm_dd-hhnnss")
                Else
                    ProjectID = "E-" & Format(Initial_Contact, "yyyy_mm_dd_hhnnss")
                End If
                
                From = .SenderName
            End Select
        End With
        
        With rst
            .FindFirst "[EntryID] = '" & EntryID & "'"
            If .NoMatch Then
                .FindFirst "[ProjectID] = '" & ProjectID & "'"
                If .NoMatch Then
                    .AddNew
                        .Fields("ProjectID") = ProjectID
                        .Fields("From") = From
                        .Fields("Initial_Contact") = Initial_Contact
                        
                        If InStr(ProjectID, "PLA") Then
                        .Fields("ETA") = Functions.ETA(CStr(Initial_Contact), "PLA", 1)
                        Else
                        .Fields("ETA") = Functions.ETA(CStr(Initial_Contact), "E", 0)
                        End If
                        
                        If Email.Categories = "Flo-Thru" Then
                        .Fields("Flo_Thru_Email") = True
                        Else: .Fields("Flo_Thru_Email") = False
                        End If
                        
                        .Fields("Found") = True
                Else
                    .Edit
                End If
                    .Fields("Subject") = Subject
                    .Fields("EntryID") = EntryID
                .Update
            Else
                .Edit
                    .Fields("Subject") = Subject
                    If Email.Categories = "Flo-Thru" Then
                        .Fields("Flo_Thru_Email") = True
                    Else: .Fields("Flo_Thru_Email") = False
                    End If
                    .Fields("Found") = True
                .Update
            End If
        End With
    Next Email
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    
    With DoCmd
        .RunSQL "DELETE * FROM Email_Info WHERE [Found] = False and IsNull([CompletedDate])"
        .RunSQL "UPDATE Email_Info SET [Found] = False"
    End With
'----------------------------------Timer-----------------------------------
SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
MsgBox "Time lapse = " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", , "App Email Search Time Lapse"
'----------------------------------Timer-----------------------------------
Exit Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Since VBA does not support [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) of boolean expressions, your current code must evaluate each & every `InStr` expression within the test expression for the `If` statement before determining whether or not the test expression is validated.

To avoid this, I would suggest using a function which returned a boolean value as soon as a match is found, to minimise the number of `InStr` tests.

Such a function could be:

```vb
Function SearchString(strStr As String, strCSV As String) As Boolean
    Dim strItm
    For Each strItm In Split(strCSV, ",")
        If InStr(strStr, strItm) Then
            SearchString = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next strItm
End Function
```

Which could be used in your code in the following way:

```vb
If SearchString(.Body, "hsarep,repcosalesofga,p-massoc,tchristy,mlsalesinc,vcmsales,ssafla,bellsouth,jim-bryce,millermays,kennymma,hhrep,bankcs@aol,dtoddcpd,colleenmartinhandh,ppg-sales,asapsales,mechagents,e-technical@zurn.com,Barbara.Cass,Craig.Comito,comfortsystemsusa,hmmechanical,gsphinc,dynaten,ColonialWebb,bchmechanical,rbiva,naminc,designmech,marelich,gowaninc,emcorgroup,emcor,comunale,shambaugh,trautman-shreve,ccimechanical,scaliseindustries,cannistraro,brand,mckenneys,murphy-stl,eganco,jfahern,hillgrp,jhkelly,ewing-doherty,falconplumbing,hmcc,harriscompany,hpeinc,jjkllc,jwdanforth,murraycompany,southlandind,usengineering,kruckph,ppcosa,ppmechanical,northmechanical,welchandrushe,acibuilds,waldinger,precisionplumbing,osullivanplmg,mmccontractors") Then
    ProjectID = "PLA-" & Format(Initial_Contact, "yyyy_mm_dd-hhnnss")
ElseIf SearchString(.SenderEmailAddress, "hsarep,repcosalesofga,...,") Then
    ProjectID = "PLA-" & Format(Initial_Contact, "yyyy_mm_dd-hhnnss")
End If
```

Comment: My dude you are awesome! the average code time went from 26.96 seconds to 11.16 seconds! This is much faster than it was but is there any way to further increase the speed that you know of?

Comment: @Austin397 You're welcome. Regarding the execution time, are you timing this specific section of code, or execution of your entire function? Given that we are not seeing the complete function, there may be efficiency improvements to be found elsewhere.

Comment: I am doing the entire function but this section was definitely the main abuser of time.

Comment: I have added the rest of the code to the question. Thank you!